# .NET Serial Port Woes. Converting C# Code to VB

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I'm having trouble with the SerialPort function intermittently crashing while data logging for several days. It's been a hard problem to debug and I would like to try Zach Saw's fix which he talks about [here](http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2010/07/net-serialport-woes.html) and [provides code for in C#](http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2010/07/serialport-ioexception-workaround-in-c.html)

My question is, to do this, do I need to rewrite the entire use of the Serial Port in my code?

If I use the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort module, is there a way to just do a DLLImport of SetCommState to set fAbortOnError to false, or do I need to abandon the SerialPort module entirely and write everything using the kernel32.dll?

Comment: Are you using .Net 4.0?  I don't know if that bug was fixed, but many others were. :)

Comment: .NET 4.0 still didn't fix all of the serial issues.  It did on XP, but not Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure in this case you could import his project into your solution, and it should run just fine.  Since VB and C# are both CLR languages, they both compile down to the same intermediate language.

Comment: Thanks. I added it to my project and just ran the SerialPortFixer.Execute("COM1") within visual basic. It's running now, though it will be several days before I know if it fixes my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823179

It's got the proper declarations for SetCommState, with some example code. Zach's fix is to basically open the com port as a file first, call setcommstate, then use the serial io functions in .net. I haven't tried it but his post sounds like you shouldn't have to do much at all to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Having tested about 15 different solutions to the various problems with serial ports in .NET, I settled on using [CommStudio](http://www.commstudio.com/commstudio).  It's been rock solid ever since.

You can get CommStudio Express (their free version) here:  http://www.componentsource.com/products/commstudio/downloads.html?rv=42917

Comment: Thanks! If this fix doesn't work I will definitely check this out.

Comment: I'd have to admit, I've never had good results using anything from MS serial related. Every project I've ever done that worked with serial ports I just popped for a decent 3'rd party library and never looked back. For little personal stuff, i've used it, and it's always been a pain in one way or another. There's COMM libraries out there for 100$ or so and most have free trials so I'd definitely consider going that route if you still have probs with the .net serial functions